# Is there a utility which shows me when a Windows computer was running?

Tags: windows-7, logging

In order to fill out my time tracking sheet at my company, I often use the Windows 7 event viewer to find out, when I have been turning on or off my computer. I've made some convenient filters for that, but I was wondering if there's an easier way.

Is there a simple utility which shows me the boot & shutdown times for the last couple of days?

(I know about full blown logging applications like Rescuetime or Manictime, but I'm looking for something smaller.)

Comment: Gee, what about a simple manual logbook and discipline to use it?

Comment: Because that's boring and tedious work. Exactly the kind of work we've invented computers for.

Comment: yes, but it is portable, stable, reliable probably even secure and not affected by things such as disk problems, magnetic flelds, file restores, and the like.

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea to share which i used to track users while i was administering an active directory.

You can create two bat scripts one each to log your login time and shutdown time..

let it run using login and logoff method already inbuilt in your computer.

Here is how you can make the two scripts

One : for Login recording
Open a notepad and type the following into it. save it as login.bat

```
@echo off
echo Login,%date%,%username% >>c:\LoginDetails.csv
```

Two : For LOGOUT 
Open a notepad and type the following into it. save it as logout.bat

```
@echo off
echo Logout,%date%,%username% >>c:\LoginDetails.csv
```

Now copy the login.bat file to

```
C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Scripts\Logon
```

Then copy the logout.bat file to

```
C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Scripts\Logoff
```

You are done.

Now restart the computer and login. Open the c:\ drive and then open LoginDetails.csv file either with Microsoft excel or any spreadsheet application. You can also open with wordpad or notepad too.

You can delete the records which you have already noted, as this script will append rows with each login and logout and will grow large.

Tell me if this is working or not.

thans and dont forget to mark it as an answer if you find it useful.